# ngx-mat-timepicker shows "invalidDateTime" in Brave Browser but works fine in Chrome and Edge

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Whenever I try to use ngx-time-picker package, the user will click the input box and a menu will pop up where they can select the time. However after selecting the time "Invalid DateTime". This only happens with Brave Browser. However , whenever I try it on Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge, the ngx-time-picker works just fine as the time selected by the user from the popup menu is the time displayed in the input box. What might be causing this?

Here is a link to the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-timepicker

This is the html code for ngx-mat-timepicker.

```
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <input matInput formControlName="Time"[ngxMatTimepicker]="picker1">
                    <ngx-mat-timepicker [defaultTime]="'11:11 AM'" #picker1></ngx-mat-timepicker>            
      </mat-form-field>
```

I also provided some screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: For me it's happening in Chrome browser itself

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround that I am using for now. It seems when I set the format to 24 hour clock, it works fine on both browser but when I set it to 12hr clock that is where everything else breaks

```
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <input matInput [format]="24" formControlName="Time" 
                    [ngxMatTimepicker]="pickerE" placeholder="12:00" readonly />
                <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="pickerE.open()">
                    watch_later
                </mat-icon>
                <ngx-mat-timepicker color="accent" #pickerE></ngx-mat-timepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Edit**

The issue is now resolved in version 15.1.3 of this library. Latest is 15.1.4. See link https://github.com/tonysamperi/ngx-mat-timepicker/issues/51